# How to insert a newline at middle of a file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am a new user of python. Just trying to write a script using python.
Can someone help me out.

I calculate some values using data from a file, and i want to replace the existing value with the new value in the file along with that i would like to comment out the existing value so that i can verify whether the new calculated value does make sense.
I did parse the required files and am messed up with the insertion of newline and commenting out the old one.

Would be greatful if someone posts an example.

Thanks n regards
ss213

Comment: In general, you can't modify the contents of a file - you have to read the file, change the bits you want, and write it back out. (In fact, it is possible to modify files - but it's a bit trickier, and probably not what you want to do.)

Answer (score 1):

Output to a new file, line by line, changing what you need.  Then replace the old file with the new one.

```
input = open('input.txt','r')
output = open('temp.txt','w')
for line in input.readlines():
    if line == 'xxx':
        output.write('#' + line)
        output.write('yyy')
    else:
        output.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit vague. Let's suppose you have a string

```
a = 'ABCDEF'
```

and you want to insert a newline in the middle, then you can use:

```
a = "%s%s%s" % (a [:3], '\n', a [3:])
```

Or three bazillion other ways of doing it.
Could you post an example input file and the desired output?

Comment: Thanks but i meant it other way, suppose i have A=125 in actual file and the calculated value is A=134. How do i comment out like #A=125 and add a newline with A=134

Comment: Read the file into a string (lets say called content). Then do content = content.replace ('A=125', '#A=125\nA=134'). And write it back to the file or to another file.